# How to download file from web api using token based athorization

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

How to call a WEB API method to download file when the web api uses token based authorization? We are able to download the file if we don't have authorize and if we give window.location.href = "/api/CaseDetailsSvc/DownloadCaseDoc?strFileName=" + fileName . But we would like to be able to allow only authorized users to call this web api method. How to solve this?

Here's the code we have:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "RspCaseEdit")]
public class CaseDetailsSvcController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage DownloadCaseDoc(string strFileName)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = null;
        string fullPath = "CaseDocs\\"+strFileName;

        if (!File.Exists(fullPath))
        {
            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        else
        {
            // Serve the file to the client
            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            result.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = strFileName;
        }

        return result;
    }
}


//angularJs service
this.DownloadCaseDoc = function (fileName) {
    var rep = $http({
        url: "/api/CaseDetailsSvc/DownloadCaseDoc?strFileName=" + fileName,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: authHeads,
    });
    return rep;
};

//AngularJs controller
vm.downloadFile = function (fileName) {
    var response = caseService.DownloadCaseDoc(fileName).then(function (resp) {
 //What to write here to download the file.
  }, function (error) {
        console.log('here is your error', error)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the way to solve this requirement.**

1) Build an API which accepts your auth token/creds and returns the file in binary format.

2) Use Filesaver.js to convert the binary to blob and them to the file format you want.

Note: This will work if your file format is a known file format eg text, CSV, Excel, etc. I have never tried it with a custom file format and cannot say if that will work or not!.